# Change logging format in Kong

Tags: amazon-elb, kong

I'm new to Kong concept and need to change the logging format of Kong. For example,  I need to customize the IP from the remote instances. I already tried to use X-Forwarded-For but I am still seeing load balancer IP. With that, I'd like to know how can it be achieved. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: In case you don't find an answer here, you can also try Kong's forum [Kong Nation](https://discuss.konghq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should review the rendering of the template in the `nginx_kong.lua` file

When the kong gateway starts, the nginx.conf file is generated by template rendering, and there are two files in the /usr/local/kong directory.

Every time kong start, it will be based on /etc/kong. /kong.conf file and template generation.

Source on this post:

- http://www.programmersought.com/article/8094116333/